# Tracking if an email was opened in gmail

Tags: email, gmail

I know there is some ways to know if an email has been opened such as return receipt which is "blocked" by default in most email clients nowadays.
There is also url or image tracking (with gmail downloading images automatically).

I would like to know if you can think of any other, legit or not, ways to get acknowledgment of the opening of an email ?

Edit for clarity : my concern is more from the receiver's point of view. When you open an email, is there any ways for the sender to know it was opened aside of url/image tracking ? I'm on gmail with defaults settings, but interested in other clients as well

Comment: The re is no failproof way of checking an email was open.  Someone may as well use IMAP and you will not know it.

Comment: Actually, my concern is more from the receiver's point of view. When you open an email, is there any ways for the sender to know it was opened aside of url/image tracking ?

Comment: If you use web mail, they might be able to include some kind of scripting like javascript.  Create a hidden input element containing a unique id, and have the script post it to their server.

Answer (score -1):

The only foolproof way is the good old [QSL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/QSL_card) of radio amateurs. That means that you end your mail with `QSL?` if the recipients are used to that Q code, or simply use a sentence like *Please confirm receipt of that message* which means the same.

In addition to the automatic return receipt, the manual QSL says that the message has been received and understood.

I must acknowledge that this is not really sexy, but it has been used for decades and has proven to be robust.